# Problems with selectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I´m trying to show in a selectInput the names of the variables that a file has. The idea is that the user upload a file in the app and he can select any variable in the selectInput. I´m trying to do this but I don´t realize my mistake. I found this answer but it didn´t helped me. [Selecting record date with selectInput in shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950456/selecting-record-date-with-selectinput-in-shiny-r)

This is the Ui.R code: I don´t get the names in my selectInput.

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Prueba"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Cargar archivo',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      ),
      checkboxInput('header', '¿Contiene Encabezado?', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Delimitador',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     "Punto y coma"=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(Ninguna='',
                     'Dobles'='"',
                     'Simples'="'"),
                   '"'),
      radioButtons('resume', 'Summary',
                   c('Individual',
                     'Múltiple'), 
                   inline = TRUE),
      conditionalPanel("input.resume === 'Individual'",
                       selectInput('xcol', 'Variable X', names("fileInput$file1"),
                                   selected = names("fileInput$file1")[[1]])
                       )
    ),
    mainPanel(h3("Muestra del archivo cargado:"),
              tableOutput('contents'),
              verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: you have to read the file in server.R then use updateSelectInput() to update the the Select Input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example on how to do:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Prueba"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Cargar archivo',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      ),selectInput('xcol', 'Variable X', columns())),
    mainPanel(h3("Muestra del archivo cargado:"),
              tableOutput('contents'),
              verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  columns <- reactive({
    df <- read.table(input$file1$datapath)
    names(df)
  })
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$file1))
      updateSelectInput(session, "xcol", choices=columns())})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hello @HubertL Thanks. Your answer guided me to get what I wanted. I made some changes because I got an error with the parameter columns().

Comment: This is my code:                                                                                                                  In the ui I changed selectInput('xcol', 'Variable X', "")                                                                   server<-function(input, output, session) {
tableData <- reactive({
inFile <- input$file1
if (!is.null(inFile)){
read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
quote=input$quote)
}
else {
return(NULL)
}
})
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "xcol",
      choices=names(tableData()))
      })